# Associate one-off Stripe payment token (tok_) with Customer object

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

Is it possible to associate a one-off Stripe charge/payment with a Stripe Customer profile but *not* save the card to the profile? I'd really like to organize my Customers and their purchases within the Stripe dashboard, but I can't see any way to do this. From what I can tell there are three ways to create a payment:

1. Using the `source` parameter and no `customer` parameter. The `source` parameter in this instance starts with `tok_`
2. Using the `customer` parameter, which will use the default card on file.
3. Using the `customer` and `source` parameters, where `source` is the card ID associated with the customer starting with `card_`.

I've looked through the docs and can't see anything that alludes to being able to create a payment using `customer` and a `tok_` source. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported by Stripe at the moment. You can still do this though with a few steps:

1. You create a card token
2. You add the card to a customer
3. You charge that card
4. You delete the card from the customer

This ensures that you don't save the card but still have the charge associated with the right customer.

Comment: Kind of figured that was the case. Thanks for the tip about saving/deleting, I'll certainly try that out.