# Stripe does not let a charge be associated with a customer with one-time source

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

As the title says, I am trying to make a payment using a one-time source (credit card) that is not being saved in the customer's profile. I still want to be able to record that charge on the customer's profile on Stripe.

According to [the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/customers#single-use-sources), this can be done by passing the customer's `id` in `customer` key in the payload sent to `Stripe.customers.createCharge`. However, on doing that, I receive an error stating the card is not linked with the customer (which obviously is not, and I don't want it to be).

> Customer `cus_***` does not have card with ID tok_visa

To get around this, temporarily I have applied the fix mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43554371/) which basically involves creating a temporary card for the payment and then deleting it.

I was wondering how does the API not work when it is clearly documented otherwise, hope someone experienced with Stripe chimes in on the same.

Here is the code I'm trying to get to run:

```
await stripeService.charges.create({
    source: token, // temporary token received from Checkout
    customer: user.stripeCustomerId, // the Stripe customer ID from my database
    amount,
    currency: 'usd',
    description: 'Test charge'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single-use sources document that you link to explicitly only works with [Sources](https://stripe.com/docs/api#sources), but `tok_visa` will create a [Card](https://stripe.com/docs/api#cards) object instead. I believe that's why you get the error.

If you try the code with a Source(it has an ID like 'src_xxx') that you obtain through Elements/Checkout on your frontend with, for example, [createSource](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#stripe-create-source), it will succeed, I've just tested it. You can also test with this code :

```
const src = await stripe.sources.create({
    type : "card",
    token : "tok_visa"
});

const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
    source : src.id,
    customer : "cus_xxxx",
    amount : 1000,
    currency : "usd"
});
```

Comment: Ah, I see, are there any test source IDs (like `tok_visa` for cards) so that I can test?

Comment: @aditya_m no, but you can create a source from a test token(https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_source-token) I edited my answer to show a more complete example

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it worked perfectly. Just two concerns: 1) The source `Usage` is shown as `reusable`, is it correct? (`Status` is `consumed`, so it won't be charged again anyway), 2) The test code that you've provided (`stripe.sources.create`), is only for testing to create a test token, right? In my production code, I can directly pass the recieved token to `charges.create` call in the `source` key?

Comment: 1)That's correct, the source has the `card` type and cards are reusable. But in this case you can't charge it again unless you attach to a customer first, which you're not doing. You'd get an error message. 2) Yes, this is just for testing. In production, you should pass the *source* you created as the `source` key — this won't work with tokens as I said. So you need to make sure you are creating sources in your frontend, either by calling createSource with Elements, or using the [source callback](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-simple-options) in Checkout.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. FYI I am using React Native and `tipsi-stripe` to integrate it, will call the `createSourceWithParams` (https://tipsi.github.io/tipsi-stripe/docs/createsourcewithparamsparams.html) with `type: 'card'` to get it done. Marking your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by creating the source first followed by the charge where you specify the customerId and sourceId as below:

```
            //Create the source first
            var options = new SourceCreateOptions
            {
                Type = SourceType.Card,
                Card = new CreditCardOptions
                {
                    Number = Number,
                    ExpYear = ExpYear,
                    ExpMonth = ExpMonth,
                    Cvc = Cvc
                },
                Currency = "gbp"
            };

            var serviceSource = new SourceService();
            Source source = serviceSource.Create(options);

            //Now do the payment
            var optionsCharge = new ChargeCreateOptions
            {
                Amount = 500,
                Currency = "gbp",
                Description = "Your description",
                SourceId = source.Id,
                CustomerId = "yourcustomerid"
            };
            var service = new ChargeService();
            service.Create(optionsCharge);

            result = "success";
```